# MariaDB ODBC driver for R gives strange results

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc, mariadb-10.4, mariadb-connector-c

There is a strange behaviour when importing data from MariaDB into R when using **MariaDB ODBC 3.1.3 Driver**. The table in DB I want to import is:

```
+----------------------------+---------+-----+------+
|          analyse           | einheit | MIN | max  |
+----------------------------+---------+-----+------+
| ALAT/GPT                   | U/L     | \N  | 35   |
| ALAT/GPT                   | U/L     | 1   | 5000 |
| Albumin                    | g/L     | 35  | 55   |
| Albumin                    | g/L     | 1   | 200  |
| Albumin im Urin            | mg/L    | 0   | 20   |
| Albumin im Urin            | mg/L    | 0   | \N   |
| Albumin/Kreatinin-Quotient | mg/g    | 0   | 30   |
| Albumin/Kreatinin-Quotient | mg/g    | 0   | 7000 |
| Alkalische Phosphatase     | U/L     | 36  | 92   |
| Alkalische Phosphatase     | U/L     | 1   | 3000 |
+----------------------------+---------+-----+------+
```

If I import the table into R using **MariaDB ODBC 3.1.3 Driver** I get this in R:

```
+------+------------------------------+----------+------+-------+
|  row |                    analyse   |  einheit |  min |   max |
+------+------------------------------+----------+------+-------+
|    1 |                     ALAT/GPT |      U/L |   NA |    35 |
|    2 |                     ALAT/GPT |      U/L |    0 |     0 |  <-
|    3 |                      Albumin |      g/L |    1 |  5000 |
|    4 |                      Albumin |      g/L |    0 |     0 |  <-
|    5 |              Albumin im Urin |     mg/L |   35 |    55 |
|    6 |              Albumin im Urin |     mg/L |    0 |    NA |
|    7 |   Albumin/Kreatinin-Quotient |     mg/g |    1 |   200 |
|    8 |   Albumin/Kreatinin-Quotient |     mg/g |    0 |     0 |  <-
|    9 |       Alkalische Phosphatase |      U/L |    0 |    20 |
|   10 |      Alkalische Phosphatase  |      U/L |    0 |     0 |  <-
+------+------------------------------+----------+------+-------+
```

Obviously, in columns `min` and `max` couple (0,0) were inserted into rows 2,4,8 and 10 shifting the values of these columns downwards. This happens only with this specific table. If I import other tables from DB to R I got the correct tables.

If I use the **MySQL ODBC 8.0 unicode driver** it works correctly also with this specific table. Is there a reason for this behaviour and is it possible to avoid it when using this driver?

Environment:

- Windows 10
- R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05))
- RODBC 1.3-16
- MariaDB 10.4.8
- MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver

**Update 1:** MariaODBC (Version 3.1.6) connects with all database of the MariaDB instance instead of only one.

The following script compares maria-odbc and mysql-odbc.

```
library("RODBC")

odbcDataSources()

## -- Two connections
##    ma: maria-odbc
##    my: mysql-odbc
conn_ma <- odbcConnect("tabl_curr_add_mdo")
conn_my <- odbcConnect("tabl_curr_add")

odbcGetInfo(conn_ma)
odbcGetInfo(conn_my)

head(sqlTables(conn_ma),2)
## +--------------+---------------------+
## |  TABLE_SCHEM |     TABLE_NAME      |
## +--------------+---------------------+
## |  codes       |  ci5v09_ch3_00      |
## |  codes       |  ci5v09_ch3_01      |
## +--------------+---------------------+
```

Table schema / database `codes` is not connected correct database.

```
head(sqlTables(conn_my),2)
## +---------------+----------------+
## | TABLE_SCHEM   |   TABLE_NAME   |
## +---------------+----------------+
## | tabl_curr_add |    arzt        |
## | tabl_curr_add |    arzt_ctrl_1 |
## +---------------+----------------+
```

Table schema / database `tabl` is the correct database.

```
length(unique(sqlTables(conn_ma)$TABLE_CAT))
## 35 databases
length(unique(sqlTables(conn_my)$TABLE_CAT))
## 1 database
```

Conclusion 1: maria-odbc does connect to all database of the MariaDB instance.

```
lim_ma <- sqlQuery(conn_ma, "SELECT analyse, min, max FROM tabl_curr_add.labor_limits")
head(lim_ma)

## +--------------------+------+-------+
## |      nalyse        |  min |  max  |
## +--------------------+------+-------+
## | ALAT/GPT           |   NA |    35 |
## | ALAT/GPT           |    0 |     0 |
## | Albumin            |    1 |  5000 |
## | Albumin            |    0 |     0 |
## | Albumin im Urin    |   35 |    55 |
## | Albumin im Urin    |    0 |    NA |
## +--------------------+------+-------+

lim_my <- sqlQuery(conn_my, "SELECT analyse, min, max FROM tabl_curr_add.labor_limits")
head(lim_my)

## +--------------------+------+-------+
## |      analyse       |  min |   max |
## +--------------------+------+-------+
## | ALAT/GPT           |  NA  |    35 |
## | ALAT/GPT           |   1  |  5000 |
## | Albumin            |  35  |    55 |
## | Albumin            |   1  |   200 |
## | Albumin im Urin    |   0  |    20 |
## | Albumin im Urin    |   0  |    NA |
## +--------------------+------+-------+
```

Conclusion 2: maria-odbc corrupts data when importing into R.

**Update 2:** MariaDB ODBC does not work with Excel MSQuery (MySQL ODBC does).

To see if this problem regards only R or RODBC I tried to import the data with Excel using excel-odbc, mysql-odbc and maria-odbc (the last two using MSquery). excel-odbc and mysql-odbc extracts table correctly, maria-odbc does not. The following message appears: *string data, right truncated*. I used the newest version of MariaDB ODBC (3.1.6).

Comment: What you are observing is not possible from something happening on the database side.  Assuming your expected data in MariaDB be correct, then something in your R script must be responsible for this.

Comment: The data in MariaDB are correct and will be reproduced in R using the MySQL-odbc-driver. This is not the case when using the MariaDB-odbc-driver. So, I think that the MariaDB-odbc-driver does something triggered by the kind of data provided by MariaDB (for example NA?).

Comment: Maybe...but this appears to be shifting your data around; I can't imagine that happening at all.